# unisharp filemanager not working on laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, file-manager

I have completely installed fresh `unisharp filemanager 1.8` on my project

I have used `TinyMCE` and `CKeditor`,

```
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="content" class="form-control my-editor"></textarea>
<script>
   var editor_config = {
                        path_absolute: "/",
        selector: "textarea.my-editor",
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
            "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
        ],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image media",
        relative_urls: false,
        file_browser_callback: function (field_name, url, type, win) {
            var x = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
            var y = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;

            var cmsURL = editor_config.path_absolute + 'laravel-filemanager?field_name=' + field_name;
            if (type == 'image')
            {
                cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Images";
            } else {
                cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Files";
            }
            tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
                file: cmsURL,
                title: 'Filemanager',
                width: x * 0.8,
                height: y * 0.8,
                resizable: "yes",
                close_previous: "no"
            });
        }
    };
    tinymce.init(editor_config);
</script>
```

When I try to browse images/files through ckeditor, the filemanager gets poped up with error as :

> Object not found!
>   The requested URL was not found on this server.

screenshot of this:

[image]

my `lmf` file:

```
<?php

return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Routing
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    // Include to pre-defined routes from package or not. Middlewares
    'use_package_routes' => true,

    // Middlewares which should be applied to all package routes.
    // For laravel 5.1 and before, remove 'web' from the array.
    'middlewares' => ['web', 'auth'],

    // The url to this package. Change it if necessary.
    'url_prefix' => 'laravel-filemanager',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Multi-User Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    // If true, private folders will be created for each signed-in user.
    'allow_multi_user' => true,
    // If true, share folder will be created when allow_multi_user is true.
    'allow_share_folder' => true,

    // Flexible way to customize client folders accessibility
    // If you want to customize client folders, publish tag="lfm_handler"
    // Then you can rewrite userField function in App\Handler\ConfigHander class
    // And set 'user_field' to App\Handler\ConfigHander::class
    // Ex: The private folder of user will be named as the user id.
    'user_field' => Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\Handlers\ConfigHandler::class,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Working Directory
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    // Which folder to store files in project, fill in 'public', 'resources', 'storage' and so on.
    // You should create routes to serve images if it is not set to public.
    'base_directory' => 'public',

    'images_folder_name' => 'photos',
    'files_folder_name'  => 'files',

    'shared_folder_name' => 'shares',
    'thumb_folder_name'  => 'thumbs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Startup Views
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    // The default display type for items.
    // Supported: "grid", "list"
    'images_startup_view' => 'grid',
    'files_startup_view' => 'list',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Upload / Validation
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    // If true, the uploaded file will be renamed to uniqid() + file extension.
    'rename_file' => false,

    // If rename_file set to false and this set to true, then non-alphanumeric characters in filename will be replaced.
    'alphanumeric_filename' => false,

    // If true, non-alphanumeric folder name will be rejected.
    'alphanumeric_directory' => false,

    // If true, the uploading file's size will be verified for over than max_image_size/max_file_size.
    'should_validate_size' => false,

    'max_image_size' => 50000,
    'max_file_size' => 50000,

    // If true, the uploading file's mime type will be valid in valid_image_mimetypes/valid_file_mimetypes.
    'should_validate_mime' => false,

    // available since v1.3.0
    'valid_image_mimetypes' => [
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/pjpeg',
        'image/png',
        'image/gif',
        'image/svg+xml',
    ],

    // If true, image thumbnails would be created during upload
    'should_create_thumbnails' => true,

    // Create thumbnails automatically only for listed types.
    'raster_mimetypes' => [
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/pjpeg',
        'image/png',
    ],

    // permissions to be set when create a new folder or when it creates automatically with thumbnails
    'create_folder_mode' => 0755,

    // permissions to be set on file upload.
    'create_file_mode' => 0644,

    // available since v1.3.0
    // only when '/laravel-filemanager?type=Files'
    'valid_file_mimetypes' => [
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/pjpeg',
        'image/png',
        'image/gif',
        'image/svg+xml',
        'application/pdf',
        'text/plain',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Image / Folder Setting
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'thumb_img_width' => 200,
    'thumb_img_height' => 200,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | File Extension Information
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'file_type_array' => [
        'pdf'  => 'Adobe Acrobat',
        'doc'  => 'Microsoft Word',
        'docx' => 'Microsoft Word',
        'xls'  => 'Microsoft Excel',
        'xlsx' => 'Microsoft Excel',
        'zip'  => 'Archive',
        'gif'  => 'GIF Image',
        'jpg'  => 'JPEG Image',
        'jpeg' => 'JPEG Image',
        'png'  => 'PNG Image',
        'ppt'  => 'Microsoft PowerPoint',
        'pptx' => 'Microsoft PowerPoint',
    ],

    'file_icon_array' => [
        'pdf'  => 'fa-file-pdf-o',
        'doc'  => 'fa-file-word-o',
        'docx' => 'fa-file-word-o',
        'xls'  => 'fa-file-excel-o',
        'xlsx' => 'fa-file-excel-o',
        'zip'  => 'fa-file-archive-o',
        'gif'  => 'fa-file-image-o',
        'jpg'  => 'fa-file-image-o',
        'jpeg' => 'fa-file-image-o',
        'png'  => 'fa-file-image-o',
        'ppt'  => 'fa-file-powerpoint-o',
        'pptx' => 'fa-file-powerpoint-o',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | php.ini override
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These values override your php.ini settings before uploading files
    | Set these to false to ingnore and apply your php.ini settings
    |
    | Please note that the 'upload_max_filesize' & 'post_max_size'
    | directives are not supported.
    */
    'php_ini_overrides' => [
        'memory_limit'        => '256M',
    ],

];
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue and I ended up just hard coding it and it worked for me.

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'laravel-filemanager', 'middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {
'\vendor\uniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Lfm::routes()';
```

});

I then ran `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_config` and it output:

`Copied File [/vendor/unisharp/laravel-filemanager/src/config/lfm.php] To [/config/lfm.php]
Publishing complete.`

and also ran `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_public` which output:

```
Copied Directory [/vendor/unisharp/laravel-filemanager/public] To [/public/vendor/laravel-filemanager] Publishing complete.
```

Then you will need to `php artisan route:clear` 
and also run
`php artisan config:clear`

Comment: I am sorry to disturb you this long after your answer to this question. I have had the same problem and it was solved locally by following your instructions. But on my webserver where the laravel application lives 2 subfolders down from the webroot I still have the same issue (everything else is identical). When I click on "Browse on server" in my CKeditor to upload an image, I get the same error message as above. Can you help?

Comment: I am not sure how this works with the CKeditor. Can you post the code somewhere to see what is going on. I would think the path that CKeditor gets is somehow not seeing the changes that were made.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this
path_absolute : "",
With:
path_absolute : "{{ url('/') }}/",

In your view file script.